# How to return multiple values from anonymous select statement in c#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I would like to return user and all matching projects for this user in c#.
My Code looks like:

```
    [HttpGet("{userId}/{projectId}")]
    public IActionResult GetProjectByUserId(int userId, int projectId)
    {
        var project = from up in _context.UserProjects
            where up.ProjectId == projectId && up.UserId == userId
            select new
            {
                UserName = up.User.Username,
                ProjectName = up.Project.Name
            };

        return Ok(project);
    }
```

Result I got one user and on project:

```
  [
    {
        "userName": "tom",
        "projectName": "Portal"
    }
  ]
```

In my case "Tom" has 3 projects which I want return every project for "Tom" something like:

```
  [
    {
        "userName": "tom",
        "projectName": "Portal"
    },
    {
        "userName": "tom",
        "projectName": "Elanor"
    },
    {
        "userName": "tom",
        "projectName": "Kestrel"
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Your query asks for a project with a specific ProjectID. Remove `up.ProjectId == projectId`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your select is good, but you have up.ProjectId == projectId in your query, which limits it to only the project you supplied id for.

```
[HttpGet("{userId}/{projectId}")]
public IActionResult GetProjectByUserId(int userId, int projectId)
{
    var project = from up in _context.UserProjects
        where up.UserId == userId
        select new
        {
            UserName = up.User.Username,
            ProjectName = up.Project.Name
        };

    return Ok(project);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `up.ProjectId == projectId` condition

```
[HttpGet("{userId}/{projectId}")]
public IActionResult GetProjectByUserId(int userId, int projectId)
{
    var project = from up in _context.UserProjects
        where up.UserId == userId
        select new
        {
            UserName = up.User.Username,
            ProjectName = up.Project.Name
        };

    return Ok(project);
}
```